# How can I test if an object is an overloaded version or not?

Tags: java

I have 2 constructors with the main distinction being the presence of `BigDecimal bulkPrice` and `int bulkQuantity`. I'm trying to write a method to test whether or not the item has a bulk option so I can calculate total price correctly. I'm a little lost as to how to write the `isBulk` method...

```
public Item(final String theName, final BigDecimal thePrice) {

    myName = Objects.requireNonNull(theName, "Name cannot be null");
    if (Objects.requireNonNull(thePrice, "Price cannot be null").doubleValue() < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Price can't be less than 0");
    }
    myPrice = thePrice;

}


public Item(final String theName, final BigDecimal thePrice, final int theBulkQuantity,
            final BigDecimal theBulkPrice) {

    myName = Objects.requireNonNull(theName, "Name cannot be null");
    if (Objects.requireNonNull(thePrice, "Price cannot be null").doubleValue() < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Price can't be less than 0");
    }
    myPrice = thePrice;
    if (theBulkQuantity < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bulk quantity cannot be less than 0");
    }
    myBulkQuantity = theBulkQuantity;
    if (Objects.requireNonNull(theBulkPrice, "Bulk price cannot be null").doubleValue() < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bulk price cannot be less than 0");
    }
    myBulkPrice = theBulkPrice;

}

public boolean isBulk() {

    return false;
}
```

Comment: We din't know what that method do.

Comment: Assuming that you don't initialize `myBulkPrice` or `myPrice` if you call the **other** constructor, can't you just check which value is still `null`?  That being said, your `Item` class seems like it's trying to do more than one thing.  You should consider making it abstract, and creating "normal" and "bulk" subclasses which do their own thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you initialize `myBulkQuantity` to `-1` or `null` and check its value in `isBulk()` ?

Comment: Rather `-1` than `0`, since the value could be 0.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) object instead of the int primitive to represent the presence of the bulk quantity where a `null` amount may represent that it is not present. This distinction is especially important if the domain may include all integer values. Additionally, it prevents choosing "magic numbers" in your code.

In Java 8, you may also specify your getter to represent that the value of interest may possibly be `null` by changing the getter signatures to return your data wrapped in an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) object, effectively reducing the chance that you will introduce a `NullPointerException` later on in your code:

```
public class Item {
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private Integer bulkQuantity;
    private BigDecimal bulkPrice;

    public Item(String name, BigDecimal price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Item(String name, BigDecimal price, Integer bulkQuantity,
            BigDecimal bulkPrice) {
        this(name, price);
        this.bulkQuantity = bulkQuantity;
        this.bulkPrice = bulkPrice;
    }

    public Optional<Integer> getBulkQuantity() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(bulkQuantity);
    }

    public Optional<BigDecimal> getBulkPrice() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(bulkPrice);
    }

}
```